# Why does my second Ajax change selected value not work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have a JS function fire when my Dropdown for #Job changes. Three things are suppose to happen.

- First, the `BusinessAreaCode` selects the appropriate item. This is
  working.
- Second, I fetch the Division List to populate the
  `DivisionCode` Dropdown. This works as well.
- Lastly, I set the appropriate `DivisionCode` just like I did for `BusinessAreaCode`.
  This is not working however.

```
$('#Job').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = this.value;

            if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue != '') {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetJobInfo")', { jobId: selectedValue }, function (info) {
                    console.log(info.BusinessAreaCode);
                    $('#BusinessAreaCode option[value="' + info.BusinessAreaCode + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");

                    var ddldivision = $('#DivisionCode');
                    ddldivision.empty();
                    ddldivision.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: "",
                        text: "-- Select --"
                    }));

                    var myValue = $('#BusinessAreaCode').val();
                    console.log(myValue)
                    if (myValue != null && myValue != '') {
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("BusinessAreaDivisions")', { businessArea: myValue }, function (divList) {
                            if (divList.length == 0) {
                                ddldivision.empty();
                                ddldivision.append($('<option/>', {
                                    value: "",
                                    text: "N/A"
                                }));
                            }
                            $.each(divList, function (XYZ, data) {
                                ddldivision.append($('<option/>', {
                                    value: data.Value,
                                    text: data.Text
                                }));
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    console.log(`'${info.DivisionCode}'`);
                    $('#DivisionCode option[value="' + info.DivisionCode + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
                });
            }
        });
```

I don't get an error in console log. I am sure I am returning a proper `DivisionCode` Value. Could this be a race condition? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to select the option before populating the list.  The order of operations here is:

1. Invoke `getJSON` to fetch "divisions"
2. Set the selected "division"
3. When `getJSON` completes, remove all "division" options and re-populate the list

So any selection made, if there were matching options at all, is clobbered as soon as the list is cleared and re-populated.

Move this line:

```
$('#DivisionCode option[value="' + info.DivisionCode + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

So that it happens *after* the list is populated in the asynchronous operation:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("BusinessAreaDivisions")', { businessArea: myValue }, function (divList) {
  // your code, then...
  $('#DivisionCode option[value="' + info.DivisionCode + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```